# Making tabs in Android

Tags: android

Which is the best way to develop an Android application with tabs. I have read many web sites but I have not found a way that convinces me.

**I want to develop an app which runs in all APIs.**

- ActionBar: doesn't work in API 10 and previous.
- TabActivity: is deprecated.
- Fragments: I don't understand.

I want to make an app like Contacts App (Phone, Call log, Contacts, Favourites, etc).
I need 3 tabs and in each tab I want a ListView. When you press an item of the ListView I want to show a second ListView depending on the item pressed.

I have an App which do that, but I don't know how can I do with tabs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ActionBar: doesn't work in API 10 and previous.

ActionBarSherlock offers a backport of the action bar to API Level 7. However, [sometimes its tabs get converted into a drop-down navigation instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201020/115145).

> TabActivity: is deprecated.

You can still use `TabHost` and `TabWidget` from a regular `Activity`, as is shown in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/Tab). However, `TabHost` looks dated from a UI aesthetics standpoint.

> Fragments: I don't understand.

Since they have been around for nearly 2.5 years, you might consider [learning how to use them](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

> I want to make an app like Contacts App (Phone, Call log, Contacts, Favourites, etc).

The Contacts app [uses a `ViewPager`, with fragments as the pages](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/activities/DialtactsActivity.java). You do not have to use fragments for pages in a `ViewPager`, though it does tend to make things a bit easier IMHO.

Comment: Which is the best way for you? Fragments? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoGonzalez: "Which is the best way for you?" -- for a modern-looking app, I recommend `ViewPager` and a suitable tab indicator (`PagerTabStrip`, `TabPageIndicator` from the [ViewPagerIndicator project](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/), etc.). "Fragments?" -- fragments are not tabs, any more than `ListViews` are tabs. Fragments are the *contents* of tabs in many cases, but something else is providing the tabs themselves.

Comment: I think that you don't understand my problem. My English is not good. I want three tabs and in each tab show different information. In the first tab I want to show a ListView and when you press an item show another ListView in the same tab. I think I don't need ViewPager for that.

Comment: @DiegoGonzalez: You are welcome to use action bar tabs. You are welcome to use `TabHost`. You are welcome to use `FragmentTabHost`. Or you are welcome to follow my recommendation. You asked me "which is the best way for you?", and I answered it. You do not *have* to use `ViewPager`. `ViewPager`, however, IMHO, is the leading tab solution in use today.

Comment: Ok thanks. Tomorrow I'll try your recommendation. Thanks a lot.