# How to show action bar tabs on different line?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am using ActionBarTabs to implement 3 tabs in an activity. The tabs display properly in portrait mode below the action bar  When I switch to landscape mode, the tabs are placed at the same line with actionbar. How can I force the tabs to display individually in landscape mode ( below the action bar )?

my code is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabhost_act);

    /* Action Bar Color change on create*/  
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    ActionBarColor.setBackgroundColor(actionBar);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);     
    getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"white\" face=\"verdana,arial\">" + getString(R.string.air) + "</font>"));


    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    /* To Get Unique Device id */
    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    szImeiId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE.

    // get User Details from Session
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap = session.getUserDetails();
    usrNm = hashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_USRNM);      

    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vp.setAdapter(new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    ab = getActionBar();


    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = ab.newTab();
    tab1.setText("INFO");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);


    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = ab.newTab();
    tab2.setText("PORT");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = ab.newTab();
    tab3.setText("PACKAGES");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    ab.addTab(tab1);
    ab.addTab(tab2);
    ab.addTab(tab3);    
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);<--used bt not working 

    // for calling fragment instnace 
    adapter=new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

refered same question 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200952/actionbarsherlock-tabs-in-landscape-orientation)

```
<com.eanda.frete_sales.common.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    style="@style/My.TabText.Style">

</com.eanda.frete_sales.common.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200952/actionbarsherlock-tabs-in-landscape-orientation

Comment: yes i already given link for same but not working

Comment: @AditiK use viewpager tab u can place it anywhere in ur layout

Comment: I am using view pager only..see code above

Comment: @AditiK in viewpager having tab also just google it

Comment: use [Jake Wharton's Tab Page Indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) if you wanna display tabs in different line and it's easy to style. But why do you wanna display tabs in different line in landscape mode? Is it absolutely necessary?

Comment: @droidster ...ok but yes i want to show it on different line its needed

Comment: Check this solution. Worked fine for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459902/force-stacked-tabs