# How to change selected Tab background color programatically or using xml in ActionbarTab?

Tags: android, tabs

how to change specific tab color change **on select event** of Actionbar Tab
i am using Actionbar Tab with view Pager 
tabs created programatically

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? can you accept an answer or add the right answer to close this question and get it off the unanswered list, thanks!

Comment: @ Nick Cardoso sorry yet not resolved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabStyle" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

*or* in code:

```
    TextView v = new TextView(...);
    v.setBackground(R.drawable.my_bg);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    ActionBar.Tab tab = bar.getTabAt(position);
    tab.setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: thnks but tht will show me whole tab bar color change insted specific

Comment: You make your drawable use a selector (if you are just trying to make the selected tab another colour?)

Comment: please read my question again i want to change color for Selected tab of actionbar TAB not the actionBar

Comment: both methods *are* the tab, but your right, i put the wrong code on a line, I've fixed it now

Comment: plz check out question posted by me [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402936/how-to-show-action-bar-tabs-on-different-line)

Comment: If you wanted me to answer it, I'm sorry but I have no idea what causes the other issue.

Answer (score 1):

to programatically change the tab's background color

```
 myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
   int tab = myTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    View view = myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
  }
 });
```

Comment: I am suing ActionBar tab instead TabHost

Comment: i used  vp.getChildAt(tab.getPosition()).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); but not working properly

Comment: if you are using the color code then don't forget to parse the color code Ex.  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));